# How to get both the attributes and the data list with XmlList

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have XML files which contain elements like so:

```
<element attribute1="a" attribute2="b" attribute3="c">
    a b c d e f g
</element>
```

Is there a way to get both the attributes and also get the value as a list?

I could use @XmlList to get just a list [a, b, c, d, e, f, g], but then I would not have the attributes. I could make a class for the element and use @XmlAttribute and @XmlValue, but then the value would not be as a list.

If there is no way to do this, I will make a class for the element in which a getter method returns the String value as an array or list, and that will be simple enough, but I was just wondering if there is any correct way to have the XML unmarshalled properly in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@XmlValue` can be applied to a `List` property.  With this mapping the list items will be represented as a space separated list in the XML.  You can do the following:

**Element**

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Element {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String attribute1;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String attribute2;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String attribute3;

    @XmlValue
    private List<String> value;

}
```

**Demo**

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Element.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum17775900/input.xml");
        Element element = (Element) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(element, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<element attribute1="a" attribute2="b" attribute3="c">a b c d e f g</element>
```

Comment: Wow, you can do @XmlValue and define it as just a String and it will get the whole value, or just define it as a List instead and it just knows what you want and splits it! It is too easy! The people who made this did an amazing job.